# How should the Maxwell's equations be understood and used?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I think I have a gap in how the Maxwell's equations describe the electric and magnetic fields. At first glance I used to think that the Maxwell's equations particularly the Faraday's law and the Ampere's law are about how the electric fields and the magnetic fields can  and actually do generate each other. So in this framework we have the ability to independently set the electric and magnetic fields individually (at the beginning) and then upon time varying either of them lets say the electric field will create a magnetic field that adds on top of the existing magnetic field which was chosen by ourselves.

But this view creates confusion when I apply it to a moving charge which has a time varying electric and magnetic field, which means an electric field(or magnetic) can influence itself through the other which seems nonphysical.

***Resolution***:

But then it clicked on me that maybe Maxwell equations are actually the true conditions of the field everywhere i.e. its the only electric and magnetic field states that are allowed, which means you cannot have arbitrary functions for $\bf \vec E (x, t)$ and $\bf \vec B (x, t)$ but only those related through the Maxwell's equations. They are determined and caused by the charges and currents existing globally and therefore there is no **generation** of one from the other. Whenever we see a time varying electric field there always happens to be a magnetic field.

*But saying that the varying electric field generated the magnetic field would imply that the magnetic field at that point could be any value but this much of magnetic field would exist on top of whatever arbitrary magnetic field that we chose in the background.*

So is my resolution true? If then why do people still insist that locally the electric and magnetic fields can generate each other? Such as: https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.1197

> What then should we teach students? I have argued that we should teach that
> spatially varying magnetic (electric) fields cause electric (magnetic) fields to
> change in time. As Hill argues, we should not teach that temporally changing
> magnetic fields cause electric fields. 1 He advocates teaching the retarded causes
> from charges and currents. 1,2 This has the advantage that students are
> comfortable with charges and currents as the origin of static fields. However
> such an explanation leaves unexamined how the cause propagates across space
> to produce its final effect. Retarded causes are not local causes.

> However a locally causal explanation of classical electrodynamics requires their differential
> form. The integral form are not locally causal because they describe the behavior
> of fields over extended regions. As explained by Hill, 1,2 they describe field
> correlations, and I agree that this is what we should teach students until they are
> ready for the **locally causal theory**.

What is the locally causal theory? And how can such a theory if it involves electric and magnetic fields causing each other escape the infinite circular causation?

Comment: "you cannot have arbitrary functions for ⃗ (,) and ⃗ (,) but only those related through the Maxwell's equations." -- This is a correct statement. Sometimes given a differential equation we are somewhat loose about what is a "cause" and what is an "effect", in order to build up physical intuition, when in reality the equation relates two phenomena that are happening simultaneously. I would try not to get too wrapped up in the philosophy, and focus on statements that can be made mathematically precise.

Comment: We stopped teaching that electric and magnetic phenomena are somehow independent from each other many decades ago. The electromagnetic field is a single, integrated entity. More precisely, the entire physical vacuum is, it's just awfully hard to work with the full description of the physical vacuum all at once, so we specialize to whatever it is that we need for whatever purpose we have. Maybe we should start students in primary school off on the intellectual techniques of simplification and approximation and then this would not even be a question any longer? That's for educators to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But then it clicked on me that maybe Maxwell equations are actually the true conditions of the field everywhere i.e. its the only electric and magnetic field states that are allowed, which means you cannot have arbitrary functions for E⃗(x,t) and B⃗(x,t) but only those related through the Maxwell's equations.

Yes, that is correct. Maxwell’s equations hold at every point in space and every moment of time in the system. They are better thought of as constraint equations rather than cause-effect relations.

In fact, they do not have the proper mathematical form for cause-effect relationships. Causes always come before effects, but the left and right hand sides of Maxwell’s equations happen at the same time. A correct causal relationship is written as $$effect(t)=cause(T)$$ where the effect at time $t$ depends only on the cause at times $T<t$. Maxwell’s equations do not have this form, so they are not cause-effect equations.

Electromagnetism can be written in a cause effect style in Jefimenko’s equations, or more easily in terms of scalar and vector retarded potentials. $$\phi(t,r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(t_r,r’)}{|r-r’|}dV’$$$$A(t,r)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{J(t_r,r’)}{|r-r’|}dV’$$$$t_r=t-\frac{|r-r’|}{c}<t$$Since $t_r<t$ this is a causal relationship. And we see that the fields do not cause each other. Rather, the fields are caused by the charge and current densities.

Then it is clear that if we know the E or B fields then Maxwell’s equations give us good information about the other. But that information is known because we know how the fields are constrained, and the causal relationship is a different one.

I don’t think that I agree with the point that Jefimenko’s equations are non-local. As $t_r\to t$ we have $r-r’\to 0$, which seems perfectly local to me.

Comment: +1, just a minor (mostly semantic) point: "They are better thought of as constraint equations".. technically some Maxwell equations are constraints (e.g. B is solenoidal), others are genuine evolution equations. This is better seen if one writes them as an "initial value problem" (Cauchy problem) for the time evolution of initial conditions imposed on a spacelike volume (the constraints are to be imposed on the initial conditions and are then automatically preserved during evolution).

Comment: @Quillo that is a good point. I am not sure how to state that concisely. I will think about it a bit

Answer (score -1):

This needs to be understood with some understanding of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition

That is, if you know how the fields behave in the limit to infinitely far away, then Maxwell's equations actually describe enough information for you to generate, for every neighbourhood of a point, what happens in the next time step, provided that you also know what the boundary terms are (which might need you to progressively solve for bigger and bigger volumes, until you reach infinite volume, or some tolerance, or some prescribed boundaries. Then you can make one tiny time step forward. Maybe you have to even integrate all the way back to the infinite past, and some suitable assumptions on the fields in the infinite past.

So yes, you may not arbitrarily setup fields. Maxwell's equations are already fully determining the behaviour of the fields.

Local causal theory simply means what it says: Local means if you just want to know about the neighbourhood of a point, you can setup the integral for the volume near the point, and solve for a solution once you know what the boundary of that volume is doing (or assume it becomes less important after some distance). Causal means effects comes after causes, i.e. you just need to know the past to know the future.

Because of the difficulty of keeping track of so many things, and their internal constraints, it is typical to accept the ambiguity of having gauge covariant quantities known as the vector potential. If you solve Maxwell's equations for the vector potential, which is a lot less work, then you will cheaply get the E and B fields. Two of the Maxwell's equations are internal constraints (div B = 0 = curl E + $\partial_t B$) and will be automatically satisfied if we use vector potentials.